# ItemType Get Object of Selected Row on RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

With the introduction of the ItemType property used for strongly typed databinding, is there a way to get that object from a databound Grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvItems" runat="server" ItemType="Item" DataKeyNames="ItemID,ItemGroupID"  OnRowCommand="gvItems_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemDescription" HeaderText="Item"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void gvItems_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        int selectedIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        DataKey dk = gvItems.DataKeys[selectedIndex];
        string itemGroupID = dk.Values["ItemGroupID"].ToString();
        **Item item = gvItems.GetSelectedObject(selectedIndex);**
    }
}
```

Traditionally I would use the DataKey property, but I was wondering if there was anyway to get a reference to the object, something along the lines of Item item = `gvItems.GetSelectedObject(selectedIndex);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object assigned in datasource is not available in *PostBack*  i.e. in `gvItems_RowCommand`, although you can get the `ItemType` The object is used to generated the html for the `GridView` and is not available in postback, It is the same way the `DataSet` is not available in *postback* that is assigned to DataSource of control for databinding.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the explanations, they do make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the reference to the object that got bound to a particular row of the gridview. Mainly because of the stateless nature of asp.net. The data disappears on the server itself once response is rendered to the client - i.e. towards the end of the page life cycle.

However, if you still want the data persisted, and not have to query it from the db for each postback, you could serialize the list of objects and store it in the viewstate. This depending upon the situation is good/bad. If data is small, then you could go for this. If large, then you'd have to query this everytime. Doing this alone won't retrieve the object associated with the row: you'll have to iterate that list and find the object associated with the row.